# Как добавить статику в админку

Tags: django, django-admin

Все привет!
Я сделал своё поле для формы админки(так же своё поле для моделей и виджет) и не как не могу добавить статику, указанную в Media виджета, к нужно мне странице.

```
class UploadButtonWidget(forms.TextInput):
        class Media:
            extend = False
            css={
                'all': ('fileManager/css/style.css',),
            }
        js=(settings.STATIC_URL + 'fileManager/css/main.js')

class UploadButtonField(forms.ImageField):
    widget = UploadButtonWidget
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadButtonField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        res = super(UploadButtonField, self).widget_attrs(widget) or {}
        res["class"] = "img-extended-field"
        return res

class ImageExtendedField(models.ImageField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': UploadButtonField,
            'external_plugin_resources':,
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(ImageExtendedField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UploadButtonWidget(forms.TextInput):
        class Media:
            extend = False
            css={
                'all': ('fileManager/css/style.css',),
            }
            js=('fileManager/css/main.js',)
```

Comment: Это была ошибка не в моём коде, а в его отображении здесь. Но проблему в итоге это не решает. То что указано в классе media не подгружается на странице, где был использовано моё самописное поле, но при этом, класс и присвоить смог